# .net regular expression - need help merging 'two' expressions

Tags: .net, regex, string

I'm trying to create a regular expression for .net that will:

- A.) extract a 1 to 4 digit numeric from a mixed character value
- B.) extract a 1 to 3 digit numeric IF immediately following a forward slash '/'

> **Example = desired result:**
>
> - abc1234abc1     = 1234
> - abc12345abc1    = No results
> - abc123/456abc1  = 456
> - abc1234/1234abc1 = No results

The pattern `(?<!\d)\d{1,4}(?!\d)` results in the following:

> - abc1234abc1    = 1234 (good)
> - abc12345abc1   = No results (good)
> - abc123/456abc1 = 123, 456, 1 (bad)
> - abc1234/5678abc1   = 1234, 5678, 1 (bad)

This pattern `\/?[\d]{1,3}` is resulting in the following:

> - abc123/456abc1  = /456 (should just be 456)
> - abc1234/5678abc1 =/567 (should resturn no results)

I tried putting lookarounds around the above pattern so /5678 returns no values but I am getting no values at all when I do that regardless.

My question is do I need two separate expressions for this or can it be done in one expression? One would be preferred, but I am not sure how to merge them..Thanks!!

Comment: Is `1` part of the strings? See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5b%5cd%2f%5d)(%3f%3cnum%3e%5cd%7b1%2c4%7d)(%3f!%5b%5cd%2f%5d)%7c%2f(%3f%3cnum%3e%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d)(%3f!%5cd)&i=abc1234abc%0d%0aabc12345abc%0d%0aabc123%2f456abc%0d%0aabc1234%2f1234abc).

Comment: If you are referring to the 1 at the end abc123/456abc"1", no, I just put that in there to be part of the 'mixed character value'.  The demo you provided looks great, only thing is the results should not include the / but should just be the value after the slash (IE just 456 not /456)

Comment: The result is not the `Match.Value`, but `Match.Groups["num"].Value`. See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NP1bSw).

Comment: Please let me know if the regex works for you.

Comment: Yep, I think that will work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var lines = new string[] {"abc1234abc", "abc12345abc", "abc123/456abc", "abc1234/1234abc"};
foreach (string s in lines) 
{
   var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<![\d/])(?<num>\d{1,4})(?![\d/])|/(?<num>\d{1,3})(?!\d)");
   foreach (Match m in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["num"].Value);
}
```

See  [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NP1bSw)

The regex has 2 alternatives:

- `(?<![\d/])(?<num>\d{1,4})(?![\d/])` (matches 1-4 digit substrings not preceded or followed with `/` or digits)
- `/(?<num>\d{1,3})(?!\d)` (matches 1-3 digit substrings preceded with `/` and not followed by a digit.

The value you need is in a named group "num".